# How to find Unique device identifier (UDID) of Apple Vision Pro device without Xcode?

Tags: udid, vision-pro

I'm looking for a way to give my customer instruction on how to get UDID of his AVP and send it to me so I can build iOS application for his device to test it.

I can find UDID of my device in Xcode. But the customer doesn't have Xcode. So he can't use this way.

What ways there are to get UDID of AVP device for users without Xcode?

Comment: You and your customer will probably be happier if you use TestFlight, which handles device enrollment and your beta build updates very smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use free service [UDID.tech](https://udid.tech) to get UDID of AVP.

I found the answer in one of the Facebook [communities about Apple Vision Pro development](https://www.facebook.com/groups/visionproapps/posts/419196310456214/?__cft__%5B0%5D=AZWlpf33TWoPIW9urGprzjgtP6jyPuqiuWL_M1oZIbKfXvt5xRFnETwTq4kyr8z0laeHQwPbadGIOMCN826dboSi9GpzolwxsUCmG_kv9-uf_Nd_kc4KrGAihHNv4KgSplHmIZ7srH-m2LaTlQHeDaWs&__tn__=%2CO%2CP-R)